# Hide translation key on page load angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using Angular-translate in combination with partial-loader,i want to hide translate key on page load.
 in **app.js**

```
       var app = angular.module('myapp', [
          'ngRoute',
          'appRoutes', 
          'pascalprecht.translate',
          'angularTranslate',
          'indexCtrl'
        ]); 

    angular.module('angularTranslateApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']).config(function($translateProvider) {
        $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
            urlTemplate: 'translation/{lang}/{part}.json'
        });
 $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-US');
```

**index.js**

```
angular.module('indexCtrl', []).controller('indexController', 
  function($scope, $translate, $translatePartialLoader) {

    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('test');
    $translate.refresh();

});
```

**test.json**

```
{
"testkey":"testval"
}
```

**HTML**

```
{{ "testkey" || translate }}
```

so on page load its showing **testkey** for few seconds,i dont want to show this,how to acheive this. i have already used **translate-cloak** but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Either load one language statically and set it as preferred language with `$translate.preferredLanguage()`, so there is data to show right away, when the page loads for the very first time.

Or use the `$translateChangeSuccess` event to apply a custom CSS class to your elements, i.e. hide them on default and make them visible as soon as language was set properly. This way you will not see the translation keys, since they are hidden initially.

Also have a look at the paragraph about FOUC in [this article](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading).

Answer (score 0):

can you please try that on resolve of that page in routeconfig

```
    resolve: {
           translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart('test');          
                return $translate.refresh();
           }]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`translate-cloak` directive needs to be accompanied by `.translate-cloak{opacity:0}` style.(This style hides the content). On `"translateChangeSuccess"` event `$translate` service removes the class and you can have the actual values displayed.